# Pandas square bracket chaining vs double indexes in single brackets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Considering I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
purchase_1 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Chris',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Dog Food',
                        'Cost': 22.50})
purchase_2 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Kevyn',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Kitty Litter',
                        'Cost': 2.50})
purchase_3 = pd.Series({'Name': 'Vinod',
                        'Item Purchased': 'Bird Seed',
                        'Cost': 5.00})
df = pd.DataFrame([purchase_1, purchase_2, purchase_3], index=['Store 1', 'Store 1', 'Store 2'])
```

what is the difference between `df_slice = df.loc['Store 1', 'Cost']` and `df_slice = df['Cost']['Store 1']`? When I change the value of these slices, the original dataframe is modified in both cases. Although when I try to change the value of the slice from the first option, it raises an error when ran in Jupyter Notebook: **SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame**.

Comment: this is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second method is an example of chained indexing, which can result in copy warnings / failures in some cases. [In this  page](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy), the problem explained clearly.